# Clicking a button in Chrome using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tampermonkey

I am trying to click a button on a page in Google Chrome using `document.querySelector` and I used the inspect tool to find the exact path of the button in JS. This is what I tried:

```
window.deactivate = function() {
       document.querySelector("JS path of the button").click();
}
```

However, this code didn't seem to work as the button wasn't clicked. I know for a fact that there is no issue with the actual function being called because there are other things that are working fine which are in the same function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just declared a function here.

Now you need to call it, like that:

```
window.deactivate();
```

Comment: I don't see that in your [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: jQuery(document).on('click', '#search_cancel_button', deactivate);

Comment: This is what I used.

Comment: Also there is no such thing as "JS path" but there is [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: This is what the JS path looks like:

Comment: body > main > section > section > div > div.ut-market-search-filters-view.floating > div.ut-pinned-list-container.ut-content-container > div > div.ut-pinned-list > div.search-prices > div:nth-child(3) > div.ut-numeric-input-spinner-control > button.btn-standard.increment-valu